# How to parse multi-line JSON response to exact a particular key's value?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I'm trying to parse a multi-line JSON response to get a value for a key using JavaScript. I read we can't parse multi-line json, how I can achieve getting "Created" value from below json?

1. I tried converting the JSON to string and used replace to converting multi-line to single line with \n as deliminator. -- Unable to replace multi-liner text.
2. I tried extracting index of mischief key value and remove from the string -- Syntax error.

   ```
   var v1 =  {
       "data": {
           "type": "articles",
           "id": "1",
           "attributes": {
               "title": "JSON:API paints
   my bikeshed!",
               "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
               "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
               "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
           },
           "relationships": {
               "author": {
                   "data": {
                       "id": "42",
                       "type": "people"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   };
   alert(result.data.attributes.created);
   ```

My expectation is to get  2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z as output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In case of new line you can replace all the new lines and then parse
  the JSON.
- Each OS generate different newline characters you need to
  be aware of that while replacing newline characters.

```js
var v1 =  `{
    "data": {
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "JSON:API paints
my bikeshed!",
            "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
            "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
            "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "author": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "42",
                    "type": "people"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`;

var result = v1.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');

var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);

console.log(resultObj.data.attributes.created);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example i see syntax error

Try to change string definition "" to ``

```js
var v1 =  {
    "data": {
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "title": `JSON:API paints
my bikeshed!`,
            "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
            "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
            "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "author": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "42",
                    "type": "people"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(v1.data.attributes.created)
```